# Writing a tab delimited file as json object in python

Tags: python, json

I have a tab delimited file of the form:

```
123 91860   Sun Mar 16 08:06:25 +0000 2014  feeling terrible.
789 12139   Sun Mar 16 09:01:07 +0000 2014  children are the blessing of god.
```

Now i want to write this file as a json object like this:

```
{"data": [{"text": "feeling terrible.","id": 123},{"text": "children are the blessing of god","id": 678}]}
```

I want to write the code for this in python:

```
import json
f=open("tree_0","r")
for line in f:
    lines=line.split('\n')
    data=lines[0].split("\t")
    id=str(data[0])
    text=str(data[3])
```

Please tell me how to dump the id and text in json so that I get the desired output.

Comment: Use the csv module. You'll need csv.DictReader: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
import json
data={}
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile,open("tree_0","r") as f:
    for line in f:
       sp=line.split()
       data.setdefault("data",[]).append({"text": sp[-1],"id": sp[0]})
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

All you need is loop over you lines and split it, then create your expected dictionary.you can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method for this task.

Then use `json.dump` to write your data to file!